# Does Windows ever change an encoding upon move or read?

Tags: windows, encoding, binary

I have a central repository where I store some binary (zip) files. A client can download specific files from this repository, unzips them locally and then places the resulting files in a designated folder.

At some point, this changes the encoding of one of the files in the stored zip. I have no explanation for why this happens, but it does. My own files are in UTF-8 and contain a character whose code point is represented as C3B3 in a hex editor. The client changes the encoding of at least one of these files to Windows-1252, so that the character is represented as F3. This happens on their machine, but not on mine, for the same operation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all checks out, 0xc3 0xb3 is the utf-8 encoding for ó and that's indeed 0xf3 in code page 1252.  Zip archives do have code page awareness, it stores strings.  But that only applies to the dictionary for the archive, the names of the files.  And a possible password.  Never to the zipped files themselves, they are just treated like binary blobs of bytes.

The much more likely scenario here is that whatever program the customer uses to read the file is making this conversion.  Could be Notepad for example.  A very long distance shot is that the unzipper that the customer uses is somehow aware that the zipped file is a text file, pretty unlikely.  You'll need to get ahead by asking the customer what exactly they do with the .zip archive.

Comment: It turns out one of my co-workers made a careless decision by implementing an unzip using a snippet found online. At a certain point, it transforms a byte stream into a character stream, using the default platform encoding.

Comment: Tsk, tsk.  Didn't guess that the long distance shot would pan out :)